# Why this code is showing terminated due to timeout on hackerrank

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, mergesort

Question is- Merge two sorted linked lists .
For details -visit https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists
When i am submitting this on site, it shows "Terminated due to timeout".Please tell me what is wrong with code,and how to fix it.

```
Node MergeLists(Node headA, Node headB) {
 // This is a "method-only" submission. 
 // You only need to complete this method 
if(headA==null){
    return headB;
}else if(headB==null){
    return headA;
}else{
    Node h,t;
    if(headA.data>=headB.data){
        h=headB;
        t=h;
        h=h.next;
        headB=headB.next;
    }else{
        h=headA;
        t=h;
        h=h.next;
        headA=headA.next;
    }
    while(headA!=null && headB!=null){
        if(headA.data>=headB.data){
        h.next=headB;
        h=h.next;
        headB=headB.next;
    }else{
        h=headA;
        h=h.next;
        headA=headA.next;
    }
    }
    if(headB==null){
        h=headA;
    }
    return t;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain in words what your algorithm attempts to do? (in more detail than merge lists)

Comment: The statements setting h to h.next in the if statement where t as the head of the result list is determined, are incorrect. h points to the node where the link to the successor must be set in field next, but for the first node this is the first node; only after that it is to be advanced. Also, the last if statement doesn't look right; it ought to contain a h.next on the left hand side and should be symmetrical w.r.t. lists A and B.

Comment: Thanks laune,I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't appear to properly merge the two lists, laune commented on most of the errors, plus the code following the else in the while() loop needs a fix (it should follow the same logic as the if in the while() loop). The timeout probably occurs not because your code takes too long, but because the hackerrank post merge check on the returned merged list is stuck in a cycle or following a bad reference.

Try creating a test program that calls your MergeLists function in order to debug it.

To get around the limitation that Java doesn't have pointers to pointers, you could simplify the code using a dummy node:

```
    Node t = new Node;
    Node h = t;
    // ... h.next = ... merge the lists while advancing h
    return t.next;
```